# How can I get an already loaded module from a file path in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, filepath

I have some file paths inside a directory and I would like to get the related module for each Python files.

```
python_file_suffix = u".py"
for element_name in os.listdir(path):
    element_path = join(path, element_name)
    if isfile(element_path):
        if element_path.endswith(python_file_suffix):
            # I don't know the module name here
            module_name = "???"
            source = imp.load_source(module_name, element_path)
            # Then I want to get all methods of my Python file
```

I don't think I can use **imp** to load my file for two reasons:

- I do not know the module name
- I do not want load again this module (if possible)

My ultimate goal is get methods information (name, docstring, ...) for each file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The module name *is whatever you want to name it*.

Comment: Use [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path#os.path.basename) to get the file name from the full path, then use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to load the module.

Comment: Why don't you create a package???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I had some issue with a fake module name when I tried it (RuntimeWarning: Parent module not found)

Comment: @M07 are you using a fake-name with a `.` dot in it?

Comment: @ChristianDean I have tried your solution, but I have an issue "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported." I have wrotten "source = importlib.import_module(element_path)" where  element_path is my full file path

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, indeed without it. it works fine. I can do it that way. Thank you ;)

Comment: You should be using `pkg_resources.resource_listdir` rather than `os.listdir`. You might also be interested in the `__path__` special module-level variable, which acts like `sys.path` but locally.